# Where do I add my RSS feed into WordPress

Tags: wordpress, rss, syndication-feed

I have the feed burner code to put into wordpress but do not know where to put it into wordpress.

Comment: Why is it voted to close as "not a real qustion"? It belongs to superuser I think.

Comment: I'd argue it's actually belongs here.  It's a programming question, or at least e.c.ho's answer is a programming answer anyway.  Anything that involves modifying code, even slightly, is programming.

Answer (score 1):

Head yourself to the following file: `wp-includes/general-template.php`

Then in that, jump down to the following function (around line 1454):

```
function feed_links( $args ) {
  //--guts of the function
}
```

You'll note two (2) lines just before the close of the function like so:

```
echo '<link rel="alternate" type="' . feed_content_type() . '" title="' . esc_attr(sprintf( $args['feedtitle'], get_bloginfo('name'), $args['separator'] )) . '" href="' . get_feed_link() . "\" />\n";
echo '<link rel="alternate" type="' . feed_content_type() . '" title="' . esc_attr(sprintf( $args['comstitle'], get_bloginfo('name'), $args['separator'] )) . '" href="' . get_feed_link( 'comments_' . get_default_feed() ) . "\" />\n";
```

Edit the first line with your Feedburner URL, like so (broken across lines for clarity and to save you from scrolling like in the above code block):

```
echo '<link rel="alternate" type="' . feed_content_type() . '" 
         title="' . esc_attr(sprintf( $args['feedtitle'], get_bloginfo('name'), 
         $args['separator'] )) . '" 
         href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/example"' . " />\n";
```